# Gift a friend programmatically android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to ask if I can purchase a product for a friend programmatically through in app billing google api or not ?

I have searched a lot and couldn't find a solution .. so could you please guide me to the right direction ? :)

Comment: You question is not clear? Do you want to build an app for online purchasing???

Comment: Yes , And I want to allow users to buy a product and send it as a gift to another user

Comment: Yes you can using google api

Comment: Thanks a lot , I'll keep searching for gifting in google api.